# QuerySet in Django - returns exception

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to understand how exactly query works on Django, i followed the tutorials it´s not working I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

When I run

```
BeneficientePagar.objects.filter(nome__contains="Joao Pedro")
```

it returns

"Choices are %s" %s (name, ",".join(available))) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword "nome into field. Choices are: ID, beneficiente, beneficiente_id,join, join_id, moeda

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Moeda(models.Model):
    moeda_ficticia = models.FloatField()

class Join(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    nascimento = models.DateField()
    cpf = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Beneficiente(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    CNPJ = models.IntegerField(max_length = 10)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Favores(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    favor = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dataInserido = models.DateField()
    usuarios = models.ForeignKey(Join)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.favor

class BeneficientePagar(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    moeda = models.IntegerField()
    beneficiente = models.ForeignKey(Beneficiente)
    join = models.ForeignKey(Join)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ID
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If using BeneficientPager, you need to do

```
BeneficientePagar.objects.filter(beneficient__nome__contains="Joao Pedro")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `nome` is a field on `Beneficiente`, not `BeneficientePagar`.

You can either do

```
Beneficiente.objects.filter(nome__contains="Joao Pedro")
```

which will return a queryset of `Beneficiente`s. Or if you need `BeneficientePagar` you can query through the foreign key.

```
BeneficientePagar.objects.filter(beneficiente__nome__contains="Joao Pedro")
```

Comment: Weird, it doens´t give me an error, but it returns "[ ]". I thought it would return the informations available for this name("Joao Pedro").
And if I edit to:

    BeneficientePagar.objects.filter(join__nome__contains="Joao Pedro")

it returns the object that is on BeneficientePagar. Which is weird since i thought it would return the name that is one Join table.

Comment: `BeneficientePagar.objects.filter()` always returns `BeneficientePagar` objects. If the query `beneficiente__nome__contains="Joao Pedro"` returns `[]`, then there are no `BeneficientePagar` objects linked to a `Beneficiente` with nome containing "Joao Pedro". When you do the filter `join__nome__contains="Joao Pedro"` it returns the `BeneficientePagar` objects linked to a `Join` with name Joao Pedro".

Comment: Oww i got it. I think I am making a big confusion. What I really wanted to do is acessing the information via Foreginkey. I thought that if I could acess the data using the "BeneficientePagar" class, I mean, acessing the data in Class Join and Beneficiente. I looked up the docs on django and I thought that was it. Any other tips? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you have a `BeneficientePagar` instance `beneficiente_pagar`, you can access the related `beneficiente` with `beneficiente_pagar.beneficiente`.

Comment: Well I wanted to have acess from the the BeneficientePagar instance and acess the name ("nome" in my models) which is in my Join class.

Comment: Try `beneficiente_pagar.join.nome`.